# initializing Without Creating An Instance (Eiffel)

Tags: polymorphism, instance, eiffel

[image]
This is a BON Diagram on the classes.

[image]

Notice how in the example, the attributes were not created into instances. At run time `a` uses `take_off` from `b`. I'm just wondering how `take_off` is being initialized in the B_747 class. In my assignment, I have a case where it's like  `b := a.b` `c := a.c` where `B_747` `b` and `c` each has the same attributes, but different value assigned to each. I don't know how to initialize the attributes without them being instantiated. It says I'm not allowed to use `b.make ("abc", 123)`.Can someone give me an example on how to implement this. Also, I'm not really sure what `b:=a.b` really means.

Comment: I would ask your teacher what he means by not creating an instance? Unless an instance is created, your code won't work properly.

There is only one way you can initialize an instance is by calling the creation procedure `create x.make (args)`. Otherwise if the type is expanded, then the instance is automatically initialized using `default_create`.

Comment: In the above slides, the fact that you do not see the initialization of `a` and `b` is mostly because this is not the point of the slides as it is a slide about polymorphism and dynamic binding.

Comment: @J0natthaaann, the description provided seems to be your reinterpretation of the assignment. Posting the original text and asking about the parts that are not clear would be much better both for you to learn and for others to answer. In particular most probably the assignment is not about attribute initialization but about their properties at compile time and at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The example illustrates something else, not object creation. Answering your first point, `take_off` need not be initialized. It is just a feature of class `PLANE` that is effected in `B_747`. The slide says that even though the static type of `a` is `PLANE` where `take_off` is declared as deferred (i.e. without any specific implementation), when the variable is attached an object of type `B_747`, it uses the feature implementation from `B_747`.

Answering you last point, `b := a.b` means that a result of a feature `b`, called on an object computed by an expression `a`, is attached to a variable `b`. The latter may be a local variable or an attribute of the current class. Expression `a` may be a function of the current class, an attribute of the current class, an argument of the current feature, a local variable of the current feature, etc. depending on the context. The feature `b` called on `a` may be a function of the class corresponding to the type of `a` or an attribute of that class.